# ClassCastException when trying to get the timestamp from firestore with springboot

Tags: java, spring-boot, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to get the timestamp from a document in a collection but I get an error:

> ERROR 26920 --- java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.util.Date cannot be cast to class com.google.cloud.Timestamp (java.util.Date is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap';

com.google.cloud.Timestamp is in unnamed module of loader 'app')] with root cause

So what did I do wrong?

Here is the code:

```
    public Timestamp getUsers() throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
        DocumentReference docRef = firestore.collection("usuarios").document("XHlUdE5516ZT2EEoBBiXvW0De4z1");
        ApiFuture<DocumentSnapshot> future = docRef.get();
        
        try {
            DocumentSnapshot document = future.get();
            if (document.exists()) {
                Date timestamp = document.getDate("created_time");
                System.out.println("Timestamp: " + timestamp);
            } else {
                System.out.println("Document not found!");
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        
return null;
    }
```

I've tried everything to change the Timestamp to date, to leave just the timestamp and etc...

Comment: Are you saying you can't use the Firestore [Timestamp class](https://cloud.google.com/java/docs/reference/google-cloud-core/latest/com.google.cloud.Timestamp) here?  Without that, you won't be able to do anything at all with a timestamp field.  You will need to get that field into a Timestamp, then convert it to a Date using [toDate()](https://cloud.google.com/java/docs/reference/google-cloud-core/latest/com.google.cloud.Timestamp#com_google_cloud_Timestamp_toDate__).  This is really your only option.

Comment: You should no longer be using `Date`. It had design problems and was supplanted by `Instant` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html), 10 years ago. So after retrieving the timestamp with `Timestamp` with `Timestamp googleCloudTimestamp = document.getDate("created_time");` convert to `Instant` using `Instant.ofSeconds(googleCloudTimestamp,getSeconds(), googleCloudTimestamp.getNanos())`. After that you may convert to other java.time types if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

You're getting the following error:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.util.Date cannot be cast to class com.google.cloud.Timestamp (java.util.Date is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap';

Because of the following line of code:

```
Date timestamp = document.getDate("created_time");
```

Where you're trying to save an object of type [Firestore Timestamp](https://cloud.google.com/java/docs/reference/google-cloud-core/latest/com.google.cloud.Timestamp) into a variable that is declared of type [Date](https://docs.oracle.com/javase%2F7%2Fdocs%2Fapi%2F%2F/java/util/Date.html), which is not possible in Java because there is no inheritance relationship between these two classes, hence the error. It's true the name of the method indicates that the object that should be returned should be of type [Date](https://docs.oracle.com/javase%2F7%2Fdocs%2Fapi%2F%2F/java/util/Date.html), but according to the [Firetore supported data types](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/data-types), you can use fields of type "Date and time", which means that your `created_time` field is a `Firestore Timestamp` and not a `Date`.

As @DougStevenson mentioned in his comment, the only option that you have is to save the [toDate()](https://cloud.google.com/java/docs/reference/google-cloud-core/latest/com.google.cloud.Timestamp#com_google_cloud_Timestamp_toDate__) method. So in code, it should be something like this:

```
Timestamp timestamp = document.getDate("created_time");
Date createdTime = timestamp.toDate();
```